# How can I parse human formatted and typed text tables with a lot of variation in Java, and if regex is the answer how to properly get row values?

Tags: java, regex

I have to parse an extremely varied user input. An example would be:

```
Example 1:
March
    Morning     Evening
    (Avg Count) (Avg Count)
Birds    5.6          10.35
Mammals  2.0          3.3


Example 2:
March
    Morning   Afternoon Evening
     (Num)     (Num)     (Num)
Birds    5.6       9        10
Mammals  2.0       2.5      3.3
Reptiles 1.0       5.6      1.75

Status Avg Total: Birds 24
Concerning that numbers have dwindled since last year

Example 3:
    Early     Mid       Late 
    (Count)   (Count)   (Count)
Mammal   2.0       2.5      3.3  (Count)
Reptile 1.0    5.6      1.75  (Count)
```

Ideally user input would be standard, but that's just not 
going to happen right now. In lieu of that, what would be 
the best way to parse user input?

My current strategy is using Java's **pattern matcher** classes.
I'm using **matcher.matchers()** to test if the formatting of the header 
is a possible format. Based on that I send the text to a method that uses **matcher.find()** to 
get capture groups from the row. It would pull out the row name (ex. mammal) and the values 
say *2.0*, and *3.3* from the first example out of the text. However, the user input is so varied, 
that this method is very finicky.

For instance, I initially was pulling out the *Birds 24* from example 
2 as a capture group, because in the text it contains a similar format as the column. So I changed it to not allow any text but the row name in the line. However, now it can't pull out rows like example 
3 with *(Count)* next to it.

So my current approach is, check the header format using regular expressions. If a format, pull
out the row name and values. Even with that strategy, I am having trouble finding the right regex to 
get the row proper row and values.

My current regex for **matcher.find()** is this:

```
(Mammal|Reptile|Bird|Mammals|Reptiles|Birds)(^a-zA-Z-]*?[0-9])\r\n|[\r\n]
```

Where capture group 1 would be the row name and group 2 should be the numbers

**So I have two questions:**

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

If there isn't a better way, what would be the right regex expression to pull out the row and it's values?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `(?:^(Mammals?|Reptiles?|Birds?|Mammals|Reptiles|Birds)|\G(?!^))\h+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` https://regex101.com/r/8Yg1wm/1

Comment: User input is a text/file (if its file what type of file)

Comment: @stacktome User input initially comes in a file, which then is parsed to grab the average count section, and written to a database. I am reading that string from the database.

Comment: Would this be helpful? http://ideone.com/27l20B

Comment: @Thefourthbird Your regex definitely helps! There are still a few cases where it wouldn't. Some people also add units next to each number. We can accept a certain amount of data not parsed though. I'll go through some of my sample to see how many more I can get with your format. I'm trying to balance readability, flexibility, parsing performance, and program performance.  Thank you!

Comment: @user8402764 you could make the match more broad matching 1+ non whitespace chars `\S+` instead of only the digits. https://regex101.com/r/8EbWye/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thank you, that helps, I will continue working with your regex! Do you think using regular expressions like this is the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: That depends, a reason I can think of not to use regex is that if the requirements are extended to parse the text you have to adjust the pattern and that can become difficult to maintain (and perhaps for other developers to read the pattern as well).

Comment: I have added it as an answer. Maybe somebody will post a non regex answer so you can compare the pro's and con's.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Okay thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 2 capturing groups where the first contains the row name like Birds and a repeated match for group 2 which contains the numbers using the `\G` anchor.

Note that you could add an optional s using `s?` to match Mammal or Mammals etc.

```
(?:^(Mammals?|Reptiles?|Birds?)|\G(?!^))\h+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `^` Assert start of the string
  - `(Mammals?|Reptiles?|Birds?)` Capture **group 1** match any option
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `\h+` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits and an optional part to match the decimals
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GhoKib/1) | [Java demo](http://ideone.com/S0IfNy)

In Java

```
final String regex = "(?:^(Mammals?|Reptiles?|Birds?)|\\G(?!^))\\h+(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)";
```

**Note** that instead of using `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` to match the digits, you could might use `\S+` to create a broad match matching 1+ times a non whitespace char.